# AWS Amplify "Cannot find module" on deply

Tags: typescript, next.js, aws-amplify

I have Next.js + Typescript project that compiles fine locally but is failing on deployment to AWS Amplify. I can't understand why this module cannot be found.

Logs from Amplify state:

```
[WARNING]: Failed to compile.
./pages/index.tsx:3:17
                                    Type error: Cannot find module 'components/Tag' or its corresponding type declarations.
                                    [0m [90m 1 | [39m[36mimport[39m { [33mEntry[39m[33m,[39m getEntries } [36mfrom[39m [32m"lib/data"[39m[33m;[39m[0m
                                    [0m [90m 2 | [39m[36mimport[39m styles [36mfrom[39m [32m"./_index.module.css"[39m[33m;[39m[0m
                                    [0m[31m[1m>[22m[39m[90m 3 | [39m[36mimport[39m [33mTag[39m [36mfrom[39m [32m"components/Tag"[39m[33m;[39m[0m
                                    [0m [90m   | [39m                [31m[1m^[22m[39m[0m
                                    [0m [90m 4 | [39m[36mimport[39m [33mRef[39m [36mfrom[39m [32m"components/Ref"[39m[33m;[39m[0m
                                    [0m [90m 5 | [39m[0m
                                    [0m [90m 6 | [39m[36minterface[39m [33mHomeProps[39m {[0m
```

The "index.tsx" component is importing the Tag component like this:

```
import Tag from "components/Tag";
```

The component itself looks like this:

```
const Tag = ({ text, link }: TagProps) => <a className={styles.tag} href={ link }>{ text }</a>

export default Tag;
```

The file is "index.tsx" and is located within a "Tag" folder which also contains a "Tag.module.css" file, so the full path to the component from the base url I defined in tsconfig.json is "components/Tag/index.tsx" but importing it that way also fails.

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

And here is my package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build && next export",
    "watch": "next-remote-watch ./posts",
    "clean": "rm -rf .next out"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gray-matter": "^4.0.3",
    "markdown-it": "^12.3.2",
    "next": "^13.2.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "remark": "^14.0.2",
    "remark-html": "^15.0.2",
    "remark-prism": "^1.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.15.11",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.31",
    "next-remote-watch": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.0.3"
  }
}
```

So, "npm run build" works locally, but when Amplify runs "npm run build" it can't find the component. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had changed the casing of my parent folder from "tag" to "Tag" and git did not pick this change up. Fixed with:

```
git config core.ignorecase false
```

And then commit and push the changes.